# SQLite in android : blank row being entered Even after nullcolumnhack is set to null. Why?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So  this is my dbAdapter class which handles data entry in database.

Initialized this class object in custom dialogfragment. And onclick event of button of the custom dialog fragment i am inserting a row.

if i leave the edittext empty and then do onclick , it **INSERTS** a row. which it **should not**.

PLEASE HELP.

```
public class dbAdapter{
dbHelper dbhelper;
dbAdapter(Context context){
    dbhelper = new dbHelper(context);
}

public long insert(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(dbHelper.NAME,name);
    long id = db.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
    return id;
}

public String getalldata(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={dbhelper.UID,dbhelper.NAME};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(dbhelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
        String id=cursor.getString(1);
        buffer.append(cid+": "+id+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

static class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "geekslabstudios.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="GEEKS";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;
    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Toast.makeText(context,"dbAdapter Constructor Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //CREATE TABLE GEEKS (_id INTEGER PRIMARYKEY AUTOINCREMENT , Name VARCHAR(255));
        //CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_1_NAME INTEGER PRIMARYKEY AUTOINCREMENT , COLUMN_2_NAME DATA_TYPE);
        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Toast.makeText(context,"On Create Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context,"On Upgrade Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

[Toast Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Froq.jpg)

Am I missing something? Please Help.

Comment: We are not magician that we can find bug in your code and show you a solution! post some code too!

Comment: Wait I'll edit the question , was just testing/posting from the android app.

Comment: but don't you think your this testing/checking stuffs waste others time?

Comment: @PareshMayani Sorry But i have edited the question please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally came up with legitimate solution.

i'd take values from edittext to the database like this:

```
String name=username_EditText.getText().toString().trim();

long id = adapter.insert(name);

       if(id<0){
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Unsuccessfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           else{
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"YAY!!! Inserted a 
                 SQlite row."+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
```

The insert method is inside my dbAdapter class which inserts values in the databse from the edittext which a wrote like this.

```
  public long insert(String name){
    long id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if(name.equals("")){
       id=-1;
    }
    else{
        values.put(dbHelper.NAME,name);
        id = db.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

That Worked Out Pretty Well For me. Thanks Eveyone by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the EditText is empty after the button is clicked.
If it is, tell the user to fill all the fields, otherwise you can proceed to insert the row.

You can try also use the "NOT NULL" command on your table creation to make sure no null value is inserted, but i think the first option i mentioned is essential.